# Using JQuery to separate out the "value" parameter data of a selected option?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a Select object that gets the Option value dynamically populated with a set of numbers.  The code for that looks like:

```
<select name="TheServices" id="services-selector">
     <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Static Selection</option>
     <option value="6398 6390" title="Service 1" data-description="desc info here">Service 1 Description</option>
     <option value="6399" title="Service 2" data-description="desc info here">Service 2 Description</option>
     <option value="6398 6390 6399" title="Service 3" data-description="desc info here">Service 3 Description</option>
     <option value="6390" title="Service 4" data-description="desc info here">Service 4 Description</option>
</select>
```

As you can see, sometimes there is only 1, while other times there may be 2, 3, 4, etc. sets of numbers.

What I need to do is take those numbers and run a function that builds out a DIV for each number to contain the information associated with that number.

So far, I have been able to display the value data using an alert which is activated when the selection is made:

```
$(function() // Start Main Function
{
      $('select').change(function() { //Start Change Function
            alert($(this).val());
            
            var item_ids = $(this).val();
    //      alert(item_ids);

      }); // End Change Function
      
}); // End Main Function
```

I've also successfully assigned it to a variable, which then displays the value in the alert when the selection is made:

```
$(function() // Start Main Function
{
      $('select').change(function() { //Start Change Function
            
            var item_ids = $(this).val();
            alert(item_ids);

      }); // End Change Function
      
}); // End Main Function
```

The next step is where I'm having the issue.  I now need to take that variable, and break it down into the separate numbers, and create a DIV for each one.  Below is my current code:

```
$(function() // Start Main Function
{
      $('select').change(function() { //Start Change Function
            
            var item_ids = $(this).val();
     
$('#services-section').html(
  $('<div/>')
    .attr("id", "service-block")
//    .addClass("")
);
      
$('#service-block').append(
  $('<h1/>')
//    .attr("id", "service-block")
//    .addClass("")
      .text($(this).find("option:selected").attr("title"))
);

$('#service-block').append(
  $('<p/>')
//    .attr("id", "service-block")
//    .addClass("")
      .text($(this).find("option:selected").data("description"))
);

$('#service-block').append(
  $('<div/>')
    .attr("id", "service-items")
//    .addClass("")
);

// This is where I have started trying to set up the loop to cycle through the value data and create the new DIV for each number.           
    
                $.each( item_ids, function(  ){ // Start Items Function
                
    console.log(item_ids);
                
                $('#service-items').append(
                  $('<div/>')
                    .attr("id", "service-item-block")
                //  .addClass("")
                );
                
            }); // End Items Function

      }); // End Change Function
      
}); // End Main Function
```

When I test it, it never builds any new DIVs.  If I place the "console" line before the new function, it displays the data correctly in the console.  When I move back within the function, it doesn't show any data.  I believe the issue lies with how I have set up the .each(function()), but being a complete novice at JQuery, I don't understand the proper syntax to make it work.

Can someone please shed some light on how to get this working correctly?

Comment: Is `item_ids.split(' ')` the function you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`item_ids` is a string with numbers separated by a space. Which means there is nothing to loop through with the each function.

So first thing, you will want to split it using the space as the delimiter.

`var item_ids = $(this).val().split(" ");`

Next, in your each loop will need to get that value in the loop itself. Which can be referenced by using `this`

```
$.each(item_ids, function() {

  console.log(this);

  $('#service-items').append(
    $('<div/>')
    .attr("id", "service-item-block")
    //  .addClass("")
  );

}); // End Items Function
```